# Resource Manager log error while YARN is working normally

Tags: hadoop, jetty, hadoop-yarn

I submitted the spark program to run on YARN.
The program runs normally and the yarnUI page is also displayed normally but some error logs showed in the resource manager log.

```
2020-07-01 10:05:43,497 ERROR webapp.Dispatcher (Dispatcher.java:service(171)) - error handling URI: /cluster
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.isOpen(ResponseWriter.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.println(ResponseWriter.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.HamletImpl$EImp._p(HamletImpl.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet$SCRIPT.__(Hamlet.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMAppsBlock.renderData(RMAppsBlock.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webapp.AppsBlock.render(AppsBlock.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock$Block.subView(HtmlBlock.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet.__(Hamlet.java:30354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.AppsBlockWithMetrics.render(AppsBlockWithMetrics.java:29)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage$Page.subView(HtmlPage.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.HamletImpl$EImp._v(HamletImpl.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet$TD.__(Hamlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.TwoColumnLayout.render(TwoColumnLayout.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.render(Dispatcher.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:165)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:941)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:178)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.http.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.http.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1604)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$3.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.processSelected(ManagedSelector.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:249)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177)
        ... 12 more
```

```
2020-07-01 10:05:43,497 ERROR webapp.Dispatcher (Dispatcher.java:service(171)) - error handling URI: /cluster
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.isOpen(ResponseWriter.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.println(ResponseWriter.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.HamletImpl$EImp._p(HamletImpl.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet$SCRIPT.__(Hamlet.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMAppsBlock.renderData(RMAppsBlock.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webapp.AppsBlock.render(AppsBlock.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock$Block.subView(HtmlBlock.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet.__(Hamlet.java:30354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.AppsBlockWithMetrics.render(AppsBlockWithMetrics.java:29)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage$Page.subView(HtmlPage.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.HamletImpl$EImp._v(HamletImpl.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet$TD.__(Hamlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.TwoColumnLayout.render(TwoColumnLayout.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.render(Dispatcher.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:165)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:941)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:178)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.http.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.http.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1604)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$3.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.processSelected(ManagedSelector.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:249)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177)
        ... 12 more
```

```
2020-07-01 10:05:43,497 ERROR webapp.Dispatcher (Dispatcher.java:service(171)) - error handling URI: /cluster
org.eclipse.jetty.io.RuntimeIOException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.isOpen(ResponseWriter.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResponseWriter.println(ResponseWriter.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.HamletImpl$EImp._p(HamletImpl.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet$SCRIPT.__(Hamlet.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMAppsBlock.renderData(RMAppsBlock.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webapp.AppsBlock.render(AppsBlock.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock$Block.subView(HtmlBlock.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet.__(Hamlet.java:30354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.AppsBlockWithMetrics.render(AppsBlockWithMetrics.java:29)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.render(HtmlBlock.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlBlock.renderPartial(HtmlBlock.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.View.render(View.java:243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage$Page.subView(HtmlPage.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.HamletImpl$EImp._v(HamletImpl.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.hamlet2.Hamlet$TD.__(Hamlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.TwoColumnLayout.render(TwoColumnLayout.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.view.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.render(Dispatcher.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.Dispatcher.service(Dispatcher.java:165)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:941)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:178)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.http.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.http.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1604)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$3.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.processSelected(ManagedSelector.java:283)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:249)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:177)
        ... 12 more
```

The version of Hadoop is 3.0.3.

Linux info is below:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
Release:        7.5
Codename:       Maipo .
```

I have tested calling the api test/cluster path, and the result can be returned normally.

Comment: Can you share the code you tried??

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:375)
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

This means that the server attempted to flush out the remaining bytes to the client, but the client closed the connection before all of those bytes were sent.

This happens, fairly often with web browsers when the user navigates off the page, or closes the tab before the entire contents of the response have been send.

This happens even more often with clients that have flaky internet connections, such as mobile clients (such as when they switch towers, or go from mobile to wifi, or wifi to mobile, etc)

This also happens, with some regularity, when the client simply doesn't read the entire response and closes the connection.  This often is a result of a client that isn't following the HTTP spec properly.

Example: If the client knows it is going to close the connection when it is done, it should have added the `Connection: close` header on the request.

The client reads the response up until it has what it wants, then closes the connection. (such as when reading JSON or XML it will read up until the JSON or XML is complete, but not any other data after it, even whitespace).  This is a fact that surprises many developers using 3rd party parsing libraries.  Good libraries have specific configuration options to keep reading until Soft EOF (eg: the end of the HTTP response on a persistent connection)

Comment: Hi， joakim.Thank you for your answer, based on your analysis. I tracked the source code and found that this is indeed the reason. Next I will see why the link is broken